# How to convert image datatype to a readable text

Tags: sql, sql-server, navision

I have an column with datatype `image` in my table and im trying to convert it to readable text, if it's possible!

[image]

Value its like : 
 0x01258D5B85447CA2F503342BC5421299211A32CB314725B544212D332F25B5

Here is what i tried:

```
select cast(cast(Note as varbinary(max)) as nvarchar(max)) as results
from  dbo.[xxxx]
```

and

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),Note))
    FROM dbo.[xxxx]
```

I get this as output:

[image]
[image]

Can any please help me or point me to right direction ?!

Comment: Why are you using `image` in the first place; it's been deprecated since 2005.

Comment: Clearly, however, whatever the data you have is, it's not an `nvarchar` or `varchar` value.

Comment: `image` is the deprecated name for `varbinary(max)`. It's not legible by definition, it's meant to store eg GIF or JPG images, or MP4 videos.. If you tried to store any kind of text there, you have a bug. If you want to store Chinese, use  Unicode fields. `nvarchar` for text up to 4000 characters, `nvarchar(max)` if you intend to store MB-sized text

Comment: @Larnu its not mine , its for Navision database store like this and the developer back in his time make it like this for some reasons.

Comment: Then you should be speaking to the vendor, @TheProfessorandtheMadman .

Comment: @TheProfessorandtheMadman that's not text, that's a binary format used by Navision. If you google for `navision note image` you get results like [How to Read/Write Notes in Navision using C/AL](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/navisiontechnicalkulla/posts/how-to-read-write-notes-in-navision-using-c-al)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos alright i just check the link i will try it out :)

Comment: I would suggest it is encoded using some proprietary algorithm, @TheProfessorandtheMadman .

Comment: Image data is more similar with Byte array of stream. You only can convert it in string representation using base64

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to `XML` between `varbinary` and `varchar`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Note)))
```